# DonutOutputCache not working for an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, donut-caching

I have an ASP.NET MVC controller action like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[DonutOutputCache(CacheProfile = "banner")] 
public async Task<ActionResult> Banner(string name, string size = "lg")
{
    // snipped - work out which banner to show today.

    return File(thePathToSomeBannerImageFile, "image/jpeg");
}
```

And the configuration file looks like:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      ...
      <add name="banner" duration="31536000" varyByParam="*" />
      ...
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Since adding `DonutOutputCache` the image that I used to render to my browser now won't load. I can see in the Fiddler trace that a largish binary file is getting to the browser, but I can't seem to get it to render.

Removing the `DonutOutputCache` makes the image appear again.

I've tried clearing the cache etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just figured it out from this link: [Doesn't work w/ Files?](https://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/workitem/2463).

Basically `DonutOutputCache` uses [ContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) internally which works only with text-based content. Since I'm returning a binary response in a [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) it messes stuff up. Fortunately it works side-by-side with the built in `OutputCache`, so I could modify my action as follows and it works as expected. I really only needed `DonutOutputCache` for other bits of my site that are text-based. I tripped myself up trying to just have one caching attribute to rule them all.

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "banner")] 
public async Task<ActionResult> Banner(string name, string size = "lg")
{

}
```